# In Angular13, reactive Form inside FormArray, Formgroup's Formcontrol minLength is not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular13, formarray

In TS

this function called first inside ngOnInit.

```
initializeForm() {
    this.rangeMappingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      mappingsList: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

after that,

```
 public addFormSection(item?: any): void {
    const formArray = this.rangeMappingForm.get('mappingsList') as FormArray;
    formArray.push((this.initMappingRangeSection(item)));
  }

  private initMappingRangeSection(item?: any) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      fhFundDepartmentRangeMappingKey: [item?.fhFundDepartmentRangeMappingKey || this.getCustomId()],
      fundStartRange: [(item?.fundStartRange || null), [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      fundEndRange: [(item?.fundEndRange || null), [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      departmentStartRange: [(item?.departmentStartRange || null), [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      departmentEndRange: [(item?.departmentEndRange || null), [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]]
    });
  }
```

I get required error properly, but minLength (minlength in html) is not working.

html code is as follows,

```html
        <form [formGroup]="rangeMappingForm" id="gw-range-mapping-form" *ngIf="rangeMappingFormArrayRawValues?.length">
            <ng-container formArrayName="mappingsList"
                *ngFor="let rangeMappingControl of rangeMappingFormArrayRawValues; let i = index; trackBy:trackByFn">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <article>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="number" formControlName="fundStartRange"
                                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.invalid && (isFormChanged || rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.touched || rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.dirty) }"
                                class="form-control gw-form-control" placeholder="Enter Range">
```

Comment: Share your html code plz

Comment: It is not allowing me to add html code can you tell me what exactly you want to check there?

Comment: Please add the code where you show the error in html.

Answer (score 0):

minLength,maxLength don't work with input type="number".
changing it from type="number" to type="text" solved my problem.

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="fundStartRange"
                                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.invalid && (isFormChanged || rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.touched || rangeMappingFormArray.controls[i].get('fundStartRange')?.dirty) }"
                                class="form-control gw-form-control" placeholder="Enter Range">
```